# Appcelerator doesn't detect android phone

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

Goodmorning,

I'm working quite hard on my own app. At this point I want to run it on my android (galaxy note 3) phone. Unfortunately Appcelerator studio doesn't detect my android phone; Windows does. I've tried it with the new Galaxy s7 of a friend, but same result.

Off course I searched the web like crazy and found several possible (old) answers, but none did the magic.

When I consult the log, there's no new info to be read!

Does anyone have a clue where to look? Looking forward to your answers…

Kind regards!

Comment: I would recommend you to add more details to your question.

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should check is if you have set up your phone for development. You can see the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html (... tap 7 times... - took me a while to discover!)

And the small obvious thing is in Appcecelerator Studio you may need to select "Refresh devices" when you try to run the project.

/John

Comment: Hi John, thanks for you reply. I already did that.. The phone is on dev. mode. Drivers are installed. Refeshing is done... But still no detected phone...

Comment: Hmmm.... one of my colleagues had a similar issue. I think he ended up having to install the right USB drivers for the phone for Appc. Studio to recognize it correctly. The generic USB drivers worked fine for seeing the device from Windows (e.g. as a disk/camera) - but not for development :-)

Comment: did you ever get a solution for this?

Comment: What do you mean @bharal? It worked for me - that was why I replied to the question :-)  - don't know if @DimmenS got it working???

Comment: @JohnDalsgaard oh sorry! I meant DimmenS, oops. My appcelerator just won't notice the Nexus 6P, i've done literally every suggestion I could find. I wish there was actually support from the appcelerator guys anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "Windows" detects it, what exactly do you mean?  Does adb detect it?

If you run

```
adb devices
```

on the command line, does it report your device ID?

On my Mac, I run this and I can see my connected S4:

```
List of devices attached
9726ea90    device
```

I'm assuming that the Windows version of adb would output a similar report.

With all the Samsung phones I've debugged with, I always have to go to the notification bar and choose "connect as media device" (or something similar).  The default connection mode does not work for debugging.  And unfortunately, you have to do this every time you connect the device.